# compute the remainder of the BIGNUM divided by any integer modulo

Tags: c, string, openssl, bignum

given some string, let assume , `hello world`. I know that the string in bits is: `01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100`. so the value of the bits is `126207244316550804821666916`. I was able to create code that give my the value of the bits. now I want to compute the remainder of the BIGNUM divided by any integer modulus, let assume `1024`. I expect to get number between 0 to 1023. but when i trying to apply the modulo , i get error: **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

this is the code that I using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>


int main() {

    unsigned char message[] = "hello world"; //message
    //hello world = 01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100
    //the value of bits is 126207244316550804821666916
    int length = strlen((char *)message);
    int i,j;

    BIGNUM *bn = BN_new();
    BN_zero(bn);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
            if (message[i] >> (7-j) & 1) {
                BN_lshift(bn, bn, 1);
                BN_add_word(bn, 1);
            }
            else {
                BN_lshift(bn, bn, 1);
            }
        }

    }

    BIGNUM *modolus = BN_new();
    BN_set_word(modolus, 1024);

    BN_mod(bn, bn, modolus, NULL);
    
    char *dec = BN_bn2dec(bn);
    printf("%s\n", dec);

    OPENSSL_free(dec);
    BN_free(bn);
    BN_free(modolus);

    return 0;

}
```

I'm new to C, i not sure what is exactly wrong here. after the loop i expect to get in `bn` the value `126207244316550804821666916`, and its seems right. but when make module with 1024, i got error.

Comment: To calculate the residue modulo 1024, you could just take the final two bytes, put it in a uint16_t x then your result is x & 0x3ff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a null pointer as the context argument. It needs a pointer to a valid `BN_CTX` object.

For example,

```c
BN_CTX *ctx = BN_CTX_new();
BN_mod(bn, bn, modolus, ctx);
BN_CTX_free(ctx);
```

In real code you'll want to allocate the context object ahead of time and re-use it for subsequent computations instead of freeing it right away, of course.

Comment: I *think* you're supposed to use a different variable for the result instead of re-using one of the arguments, too, since the man page I'm checking doesn't explicitly say that's allowed for `BN_mod()` like it does for `BN_add()` and a few others.

Comment: Thanks for the help! may i ask please what did you mean by 'use a different variable for the result instead of re-using'?

Comment: @hah Using a different `BIGNUM` instead of `bn` for the result argument.